# Batch - break a string into two substrings divided by a delimiting character

Tags: batch-file

I have strings in the format `12341234;Super Coca Cola`
in batch where both sides of the `;` are variable-length. I want to break the string apart and retrieve both substrings. How would I go about doing this?

Update: here's my attempted solution to a problem.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%Z in ('type "C:\Users\daniel.bak\Desktop\Tableau Client Data Extracts\Master Data Extracts\clients.txt"') do (
for /f "delims=; tokens=1,2" %%B in (%%Z) do (
echo %%B
echo %%C
)
)
pause
```

What I get as output:

```
C:\Users\daniel.bak\Desktop\Tableau Client Data Extracts\Master Data Extracts>fo
r /F "tokens=*" %Z in ('type "C:\Users\daniel.bak\Desktop\Tableau Client Data Ex
tracts\Master Data Extracts\clients.txt"') do (for /F "delims=; tokens=1,2" %B i
n (%Z) do (
echo %B
 echo %C
) )

C:\Users\daniel.bak\Desktop\Tableau Client Data Extracts\Master Data Extracts>(f
or /F "delims=; tokens=1,2" %B in (2;Glaxo Smith Kline) do (
echo %B
 echo %C
) )
The system cannot find the file 2.

C:\Users\daniel.bak\Desktop\Tableau Client Data Extracts\Master Data Extracts>(f
or /F "delims=; tokens=1,2" %B in (3;Merck Canada Inc.) do (
echo
 echo %C
) )
The system cannot find the file 3.

C:\Users\daniel.bak\Desktop\Tableau Client Data Extracts\Master Data Extracts>pa
use
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The clients.txt file:

```
2;herpherp
3;derpderp
```

What's this "The system cannot find the file 2" stuff? I want it to echo "2", the first part of the first string. But it seems like it's trying to access a file named 2. What's up?

Comment: Will there always only be two substrings? Do you want `{` and `}` included in the substrings?

Comment: { and } aren't actually in the string, I was just using them to indicate what the string was.

There will always be exactly two substrings with ; between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting strings on a delimiter is a built-in capability of the batch `for` loop.  Use `for /?` on the command line to see the syntax.  You need to use the `delims` and `tokens` options.

```
set "my_string=12341234;Super Coca Cola"
for /f "delims=; tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%my_string%") do (
    echo %%a
    echo %%b
)
```

If your strings are in a file, you need a loop to loop through all lines in the file.  You just have to change the for-loop parameter from a string to a filename and the loop will do it all for you.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=; tokens=1,2" %%a in ("data.txt") do (
        echo first:  %%~a
        echo second: %%~b
)
```

If for some reason you need to make decisions based on the line before you try to split it, you can use nested `for` loops.  The outer one can read the line, and the inner can split.  Note that if you set variables in the outer loop, you have to use delayed expansion to see the variables in the inner.  Here's an example.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("data.txt") do (
    set "line=%%~l"

    REM Note that inside the outer loop we use !line! and not %line%.
    echo Processing "!line!".
    for /f "delims=; tokens=1,2" %%a in ("!line!") do (
        echo first:  %%~a
        echo second: %%~b
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help.

Comment: Hey. For some reason this doesn't seem to be working. I'll post a new question.

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak:  I think you got your answer already, but I added a nested-loop approach just to cover another method.

Answer (score 2):

I's easier than you seem to think:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%a in ("C:\Users\daniel.bak\Desktop\Tableau Client Data Extracts\Master Data Extracts\clients.txt") do (
  echo %%a
  echo %%b
)
pause
```

You need the quotes for the filename, because it contains spaces. But `for` would interpret it as a string, not a filename when it's in quotes. So you also need `usebackq` to tell `for`, that the quotes don't mean "string".

PS: your solution would also work by handling `%%Z` as a string by enclosing it with quotes (without `usebackq`, because this time, you *want* it to be a string, not a filename):

```
for /f "delims=; tokens=1,2" %%B in ("%%Z") do (
```

Comment: No, I want it to do this process for each line. So for each line, break it into two substrings, and do stuff to them. Doesn't that require a nested for loop?

Edit: nevermind, thanks. I thought that you needed one for loop to traverse the file and another inside it to traverse each string. Thanks!

Comment: That's, what `for` is doing: taking each line of the file and process it. Otherwise, also nested `for`s wouldn't work.